# How can i set right index column if sheet including some 0 number when using read_excel and index_col in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Excel worksheet that i set as input data using `index_col` with the following structure :
[image]

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe using the following code when i set `index_col =0`:

```
df =  pd.read_excel('Interval estimation.xlsx', sheet_name= 0, index_col = 0, converters={'code':str})
```

The dataframe like this:

```
    start   end
code        
1   NaT NaT
300473  2018-07-18  2018-07-28
2446    2018-07-17  2018-07-27
600398  2018-07-13  2018-07-23
603345  2018-07-12  2018-07-22
603228  2018-07-06  2018-07-16
300422  2018-07-05  2018-07-15
665 2018-06-28  2018-07-08
600831  2018-06-27  2018-07-07
603027  2018-06-20  2018-06-30
603601  2018-06-19  2018-06-29
2758    2018-06-14  2018-06-24
```

but i need keeping 0 string in the first columns as `index_col`, and i have a solution as following code in two steps:

```
df =  pd.read_excel('Interval estimation.xlsx', sheet_name= 0, converters={'code':str})
df = df.set_index('code')
```

My question is: how can i get the right result in one step not using `set_index` in `read_excel` function?

[image]

Comment: Did you tried `df =  pd.read_excel('Interval estimation.xlsx', sheet_name= 0, index_col = 0, index="code", converters={'code':str})`

Comment: @pygo there is no 'index' parameter in function read_excel;

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that by applying the [`str.zfill()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_zfill.htm) function to your index just like so

```
df.index = [str(x).zfill(6) for x in df.index.values]
```

Note that this will convert your index column to a string. I don't think, however, that your requirement can be achieved while keeping the integer dtype

Comment: I have tried your solution, yes , it is the other solution in two steps code ,first step : read sheet, second step: fill width for index column ;

Comment: I don't think there is a way to mutate the column on load. You will have to settle for two steps of code I believe